# PHP - ask user input for dates and pass to script

Tags: php, shell

I have a php script here to create login at our datacenter for myself, but this script is doing the login for next week if i run it after 12:00 on monday, and a lot of times I'm not there the whole week, so I want to improve this script by asking for user input and pass the dates that I will be there so the script only picks up on those dates. I know i have to do this with stdin and I do have a part that works, but i have no idea on how to integrate this into the current script and how to make sure i can give multiple dates

My stdin part that does ask my for a date, but no idea on how to combine it:

```php
<?php

function promptDateFromUser(string $prompt, string $dateFormat): DateTimeInterface                    
{
    echo "{$prompt} [$dateFormat]: ";

    $stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    $line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    fclose($stdin);
    $dateTime = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $line);
    if (! $dateTime instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid datetime format');
    }
}
$dateTime = promptDateFromUser("Please insert date:", 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

My login script as of now:

```php
<?php
require 'shared.php';
restore_exception_handler();
restore_error_handler();

$md = new RevisionModificationData;
$md->comment = 'Set by the dcgaccess script';

$date  = new DateTime();
$hour = (int)$date->format('H');
$dow  = (int)$date->format('w');
if (($dow === 1 && $hour > 12) || ($dow > 1 && $dow < 6)) {

    $add = 'P' . (8 - $dow) . 'D';
    $date->add(new DateInterval($add));
}

if (($dow === 1 && $hour <= 12) || $dow === 0 || $dow === 6) {
    if ($dow === 6) {
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
    } elseif ($dow === 0 ) {
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
}

$tomorrow    = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$duration       = 720;
$customerId  = 30;
$purpose       = 'DCG visit';
$phoneNumber = '';

$name                 = 'SOME NAME, REMOVED FOR PUBLICATION';
$colo = Colo::getByName($name);
Ensure::notNull($colo, "Colo for RackSpace is null when it should not be!");

$spaces = $colo->getRackSpaces();
foreach ($spaces as $space) {
    $rackSpace = $space;
}

Ensure::notNull($rackSpace, "RackSpace is null when it should not be!");
if ($colo->getCustomerId() != $customerId) {
    throw new UserException(ErrorCodes::PERMISSION_DENIED);
}

for ($x = 0; $x < 5; $x++) {
    $start = $tomorrow." 8:00:00";
    $end  = Util::stringToMysqlDateTime($start . ' + ' . $duration . ' minutes');
    $shouldSms = strlen((string)$phoneNumber) > 0;

    $req = BioAccessRequest::create($rackSpace, $purpose, $start, $end, $shouldSms, $md);

    $users = BioAccessUser::getAll();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->name === 'USER NAME') { 
           $req->addBioAccessUser($user, $md);
        }
    }
    $req->request();

    echo "Access requested for: ", $tomorrow, PHP_EOL;
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $tomorrow = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
?>
```

I'm a big php noob, so some explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Wait, you have a system that starts sessions on systems without human interaction?  So if you are not there, the session is still created?  Please tell me you do not work at  my bank, otherwise I will have to move my $ :)

Answer (score 0):

after some help from a friend, i managed to solve this:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

include('shared.php');
restore_exception_handler();
restore_error_handler();

// Constants

$timeout = 45;
$md = new \RevisionModificationData;
$md->comment = 'Set by the dcgaccess script';
$duration = "720";
$customerId = "30";
$purpose = "DCG visit";
$phoneNumber = "";

$name="SOME NAME, REMOVED FOR PUBLICATION";

// Functions

function requestInput($msg) {
    global $timeout;
    echo "$msg\n\nThe timeout for this selection is $timeout seconds.\n\n> ";
    $fd = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
    $read = array($fd);
        $write = $except = array(); // we don't care about this
        if(stream_select($read, $write, $except, $timeout)) {
            $choice = trim(fgets($fd));
        }
        echo "\nYou typed: $choice\n\n";
        return $choice;
}

// Start of program

$date = new DateTime();
$weekchoice = (int)requestInput("Which week would you like to request access for?\n1) Current week\n2) Next week\n3) Specific week number");

if ($weekchoice == 3) {
    $weeknumber = (int)requestInput("Please enter a numeric week number");
        } else {
            $weeknumber = (int)$date->format("W");
                if ($weekchoice == 2) {
                $weeknumber += 1;
                }
        }

// We override $date with the start of the chosen week
$date->setISODate($date->format("Y"), $weeknumber);

echo "Thanks, you chose week $weeknumber which starts with " . $date->format("l d F, Y") . " \n\n";

$dayschoice = requestInput("Please enter the days you want access, as a space separated list:\n1) Monday\n2) Tuesday\n3) Wednesday\n4) Thursday\n5) Friday\n\nExample: 1 3 5");

$daylist = explode(' ', $dayschoice);

$processedDays = [];
foreach ($daylist as $eachday) {
    $iday = (int)$eachday;
        if ($iday == 0 || $iday % 7 == 0) { // No Sundays, also (int)"" -> 0, which is terrible
            continue;
        }
        $add_days = $iday - 1; // Sums 0 if Monday, 1 if Tuesday and so on...
        $newdate = new DateTime($date->format("Y-m-d"));
        $newdate->modify("+$add_days days");
        $processedDays[] = $newdate;
        $formatted = $newdate->format("l d F Y");
        echo "Processing day $iday, which is $formatted\n";
}

$hour = $date->format('H');
$tomorrow = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$confirm = requestInput("\nRequest access for these days? Yes/No");
if ($confirm != "Yes") {
    echo 'Good bye!';
        exit(0);
}

foreach ($processedDays as $reqDay) {
    echo "Submitting " . $reqDay->format("l d F Y") . "\n";

    $colo = Colo::getByName($name);
    Ensure::notNull($colo, "Colo for RackSpace is null when it should not be!");

    $spaces = $colo->getRackSpaces();
    foreach ($spaces as $space) {
        $rackSpace = $space;
    }

    Ensure::notNull($rackSpace, "RackSpace is null when it should not be!");
    if ($colo->getCustomerId() != $customerId) {
            throw new UserException(ErrorCodes::PERMISSION_DENIED);
    }
}

foreach ($processedDays as $reqDay) {
    $start = $reqDay->format('Y-m-d')." 8:00:00";
    $end = Util::stringToMysqlDateTime($start . ' + ' . $duration . ' minutes');
    $shouldSms = strlen((string)$phoneNumber) > 0;
    $req = BioAccessRequest::create($rackSpace, $purpose, $start, $end, $shouldSms, $md);

    $users = BioAccessUser::getAll();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->name === 'USER NAME') {
            $req->addBioAccessUser($user, $md);
        }
    }

    $req->request();
    echo "Access requested: ", $reqDay->format('l d F Y'), PHP_EOL;
    $tomorrow = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}

?>
```